# `Could not find feature system-zlib` during building QT source code

Tags: c++, qt, zlib, qmake, nmake

I'm trying to build QT from source code in Windows.

I installed QT binary (5.12.8) to get `qmake`, the `bin` path is added to system environment.

I downloaded QT source code (`qtbase` only) tag v5.12.8 and unzip to d:\github\qtbase

I opened the vs native x64 cmd shell and run: `qmake qtbase.pro`

The output is like:

```
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... no
  udev ................................... no
  Using system zlib ...................... no

.
.
.

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'nmake'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'nmake install'.
Qt will be installed into 'C:\Qt\Qt5.12.8\5.12.8\msvc2017_64'.
```

then I run `nmake` but I had this error:

```
Project ERROR: Could not find feature system-zlib.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x3'
Stop.
```

From the config log above, system zlib is not used, I assume QT's internal zlib will be used.

I have checked my folder, `\src\3rdparty\zlib\src` is existed and `zlib.h` is there.

I'd like to know how to fix this error or disable zlib.

Comment: Have you tried following the [instructions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html)?

Answer (score 0):

@AlanBirtles Thanks for the hint, I followed the [official instructions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html) and compiled again, it works.

In the official instruction, `configure.bat` is used instead of my direct use of `qmake`.

There is one more difference in my second try: I use the src code in `C:\Qt\Qt5.12.8\5.12.8\Src`, not the code from github in `d:\github\qtbase`.
The code in C:\Qt is downloaded during my installation of binary QT, because I checked the source code item in the installation.